# In Lyx lines go outside the page in the pdf file after choosing a larger font

Tags: math-mode, lyx, line-breaking

I wanted to convert my lyx file into pdf but with a larger (than the default base) font size.

I was told to go to *Documents -> Settings -> Document Class* and choose Article (Standard Class with Extra Font Size) and then to print in *Custom* the available font size (which is 8pt, 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt).

It worked but it came with a price. Because some of the lines in the source lyx-file are long, these lines go outside the page in the pdf file.

[image: lines stretch out]

The obvious way out is to edit the source file manually, but there are too many lines like these ones.

Is there any way Lyx could fix that problem automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no automatic way of fixing that. You'll need to add linebreaks in the math manually.

If you right click in the math and look under the AMS environments submenu, you can choose between various multi-line math environments. If you want some form of alignment, for example at equal signs, you can try *align*. For a single long expression you can try *multline*, in which the first line is left aligned on the page, the last line is right aligned, and the rest are centered. For a series of expressions/equations all of which should be centered, try the *gather* environment.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to add line breaks.

Comment: (Technically you could turn the equations into inline equations, also done via the right click menu, which can break across lines, but I think I would go the manual route)

Comment: Would the [breqn](https://ctan.org/pkg/breqn) package be helpful in this situation?

Comment: @scottkosty Well, yes and no. Its purpose is automatic line breaking of display math, but the environments are different, and LyX has no support for them (I think?), so you might end up having to use ERTs to some extent. The package also has some known deficiencies (see section 5 and 6 in the manual), and if you're unlucky it won't work properly. That said, I don't really have much experience with `breqn` myself though (and not at all in LyX), so I might be painting a too dark picture.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks for the explanation.